# ImportError: install Coral on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, google-coral

I've just purchased a coral USB TPU and followed to instructions at coral.ai/docs/setup/ to install it on a Mac running Big Sur 11.3 but when I ran the example code:

```
python3 examples/classify_image.py \
--model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
--labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt \
--input test_data/parrot.jpg
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/scripts/python scripts/coral/pycoral/examples/classify_image.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pycoral.pybind._pywrap_coral import GetRuntimeVersion as get_runtime_version
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycoral/pybind/_pywrap_coral.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libedgetpu.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycoral/pybind/_pywrap_coral.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

has something not installed properly?

Comment: Were you able to install the edgetpu runtime on Mac 11.3 ?

Comment: I followed the Mac OS instructions at https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/ it seems to have installed. Is there a way I can check it's installed?